# Xcode 4.5: SupportedInterfaceOrientation is not working

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, xcode4.2, xcode4.5

I am using `iOS 5` and `XCode 4.2`. After coding I gave support for landscape and portrait orientation. It is working correctly. But the orientation is not supported when I used the code in `XCode 4.5` `iOS 6`.

Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: Did u use any set orientation methods? can u put some example code?

Comment: yes.- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return yes;
}

Comment: Try to use - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{ return yes;}. It will call in ios6 instead of - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation method.

Comment: yes.. In ios6 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation won't be called.

Comment: In iOS6 i am getting call in - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{ return yes;}. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I gave return yes. Still not working. Does it need any additional coding.

Comment: Do you wish to support all orientations?

Comment: yes. I want to support all orientations.

Answer (score 2):

Please check you project setting  (Summary)

**Supported Interface Orientation** Setting for the allowed oreintations

[image]

OR

Try to lock the orientation using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown );
}
```

Comment: What is happening when a code from xcode 4.2 is used in xcode 4.5. Any issue?

Comment: No issues with respect to orientation.

Comment: Check if `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method is getting called.

Comment: i am not getting call in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: What all orientation does your app supports

Answer (score 0):

It correct way or not i don't know. But temporarily i used this method. If it useful you too can use.

You can write this method in your `Appdelegate`.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
 [navigationController.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

You can write `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` method in your `viewController`.

Comment: It is getting call. I gave return YES. Still it is not working. What will i do?

Comment: If you wish to support all orientations put the above code in appdelegate. You need to return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;